# Alternative approach to routing in react-redux apps

Tags: reactjs, routes, redux, react-router, react-redux

I've been searching for router that plays well with react and redux but I couldn't find anything that meets my imagination of perfect routing system.

In general what I hate in most popular routing solutions (for instance react-router) is that all routes are defined as a react component. This does not fit the architecture I'd like to use which is as follows: the application is divided into separated modules. Each module defines routes it uses and that routes handlers, for instance:

```
function setupModule({ addRoute, changeView }) {
    function showFooView() {
        return (dispatch) => {
            dispatch(changeView(ComponentFoo));
        };
    }

    addRoute("/foo", showFooView);
}
```

Now when someone accesses `/foo` route the `<ComponentFoo/>` should be rendered.

The problem with that approach is that I have to dispatch `changeView` action with `ComponentFoo` view and keep it in the store so that my Application component knows which view it is supposed to render. This means keeping function in the store which is generally not recommended.

Can you see any way I could use described routing system and do not break redux rules?

Comment: You can use the [history library](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history) idrectly, it's what react-router uses to manipulate and manage the address bar/URL.

Comment: I know, but the real problem is how to tell react/redux to render different view when URL is being changed